# Exporting multiple data frames from list into an excel file with name of tabs as different data frames in the list

Tags: r, list

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMp4b.png)

"Data Structure in Image"

Problem in RStudio

I have a list of 33 data frames:

growth_in   list[33]                                  List of length 33

18005     list122 x 16  tibble 176row & 16col

18013     list122 x 16  tibble 176row & 16col

18019     list122 x 16  tibble 176row & 16col

18025     list122 x 16  tibble 176row & 16col

..... and so on and so forth till 33 dataframes(in total)

I am able to export multiple CSV files but I need one excel file with different table names(i.e one excel file with 33 sheets).
Facing the below-mentioned error message after using excel_export command.

```r
excel_export(growth_in, file = "Indiana.xlsx", table_names = paste0(names(growth_in)), row.names = FALSE )
```

Error in .jcall(cell, "V", "setCellValue", value) : 
  method setCellValue with signature ([Ljava/lang/String;)V not found
In addition: Warning message:
In if (is.na(value)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Answer (score 1):

I used "writexl" package
 and used the following code to get the desired result.

```r
growth_in %>% write_xlsx(path = "Indiana.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using the package `openxlsx`

```
library(openxlsx)
library(huxtable)

growth_in= list(iris1=iris[1:10,],iris2=mtcars[1:10,],iris3=iris[10:50,])
wb <- createWorkbook()

for(nm in names(growth_in)){

  df <- as_huxtable(growth_in[[nm]],add_colnames = T)
  ##you can format your table using huxtable options


  as_Workbook(df,Workbook = wb,sheet=nm)

}

openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb,file = "Indiana.xlsx",overwrite = T)
```

I like this solution because it allows you to do some more formatting or processing for each sheet if needed.

Comment: I had made a couple of small mistakes. I've updated the code.